# Android TV deep links

Tags: android, android-tv

Can Android TV work with deep links?
I wrote a simple app and tried to open link from the browser but wasn't asked to redirect to my app.
Is this feature enabled for TVs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Android TV supports deep links. But it seems Chrome is the only browser to support it and Chrome is not officially available, but has to be sideloaded. All other browsers available for Android TV that I tried did not support deep links.